# Looking to see how many sysobjects uses tables from a particular database

Tags: t-sql, sysobjects

Looking to see how many sysobjects uses tables from a particular database.
I am running a query in sysobjects in DB (and ssis packages) to confirm how many object we would need to review before we embark..
 is there a way to identify tables used without code review??
Looking for anything from DATAbASEA with keyword "DATABASEB". 
use databaseA

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id)
FROM syscomments 
WHERE 
[text] like '%DatabaseB%'
--and [text] like '%''F''%'
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(id)
```

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

sp_MSforeachtable @command1="SELECT '?' as TableName EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'?'" ;